# Display and work with a time in a specific time zone

Tags: javascript

So I have a website for an optometrist, which is in australia. I added a small widget on the website that displays the current time and that tells if the shop is currently open or closed. The problem is, it will show if it is open/closed only for the viewer's time zone, and I want to display open/closed for AEST (Australian Eastern). I wouldn't think it was a problem, but we have a lot of traffic from Western Australia, India, UK and USA.

I have searched this a couple of times and tried some solutions like to add default time zone, but the code didn't work, I'm not sure what's wrong.

Here is the code

```html
var serverTimestampMillis = <?php print time() * 1000 ?>;
var checkInterval = 1000;

var checkTime = function () {
    serverTimestampMillis += checkInterval;
    var now = new Date(serverTimestampMillis);
    //var now = new Date();

    var timeDiv = document.getElementById('timeDiv');
    var messageDiv = document.getElementById('messageDiv');
    timeDiv.innerHTML = now.toString();
    
    var dayOfWeek = now.getDay(); // 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, ... 6 = Saturday

    var hour = now.getHours(); // 0 = 12am, 1 = 1am, ... 18 = 6pm
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    // check if it is Mon - Thur 8:30am - 6:30pm
    if (dayOfWeek > 0 && dayOfWeek < 5) {
        if (hour == 8) {
            if (minutes >= 30) {
                messageDiv.innerHTML = 'We are currently open.';
                messageDiv.className= 'open'; 
            } else  {
                messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Sorry, we are closed.';
                messageDiv.className='closed';
            }
            
        } else if (hour > 8 && hour < 17) {
            messageDiv.innerHTML = 'We are currently open.';
            messageDiv.className= 'open';
        } else if (hour == 18) {
            if (minutes < 30) {
                messageDiv.innerHTML = 'We are currently open.';
                messageDiv.className= 'open';
            }
        } else {
            messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Sorry, we are closed.';
            messageDiv.className='closed';
        }
    }
    // check if it is a Friday 8:30am - 8pm
    else if (dayOfWeek == 5) {
        if (hour == 8) {
            if (minutes >= 30) {
                messageDiv.innerHTML = 'We are currently open.';
                messageDiv.className= 'open'; 
            } else  {
                messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Sorry, we are closed.';
                messageDiv.className='closed';
            }
        } else if (hour > 8 && hour < 20) {
            messageDiv.innerHTML = 'We are currently open.';
            messageDiv.className= 'open';
        }
    }
    // check if it is a Saturday 9am - 2pm
    else if (dayOfWeek == 6) {
        if (hour > 9 && hour < 14) {
            messageDiv.innerHTML = 'We are currently open.';
            messageDiv.className= 'open'; 
        }
    }
    // closed
    else {
        messageDiv.innerHTML = 'Sorry, we are closed.';
        messageDiv.className='closed';
    };  
}     
// check the time every 1000 milliseconds
setInterval(checkTime, checkInterval);
checkTime();
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no programmatic way to get the current AEST time with JavaScript if you're not in AEST, unless you hard-code daylight savings time somewhere (assuming you'll want ADST for half the year), but that is not very robust.

The only bullet-proof way to know what the time in AEST is from any browser is to use a time service like timeapi.org or [this one](https://timezonedb.com/api).

If it was my site, I would check the user's timezone, if it's Sydney, show the clever 'currently open/closed' message, if it's not, just show the static opening hours.

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Sydney');

$current_date = date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: It's php. Original question was marked as php, not javascript.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13237586)